# Store Picture to Blob Using Firebird with UIBQuery in Delphi

Tags: delphi, blob, firebird, image

I have components:

- 1 `OpenPictureDialog` (to open picture)
- 2 `Edit` (edtID & edtName)
- 1 `Button` (to save record)

I used `UIBQuery` to insert a new record, including picture in one section.
Here is my code:

```
with UIBQuery1 do
try
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Add('INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE');
  SQL.Add('(ID, NAME, PIC)');
  SQL.Add('VALUES');
  SQL.Add('(:ID, :NAME, :PIC)');
  params.AsInteger[0] := StrToInt(edtID.Text);
  params.AsString[1] := edtName.Text;
  // How to give a param for blob here?
  Execute;
  Transaction.Commit;
  bsSkinMessage1.MessageDlg2('Has been saved.','New Record',mtInformation,[mbok],0);
except
  Transaction.RollBack;
  raise;
end;
```

I succeed show the record including picture from database, but I have no clue to store the picture into database in one click.

How to doing this? Is it possible to give parameter of picture in query?

---

Someone knows about UIB please..

I change my code but I get an access violation:

```
procedure TchfEmployee.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Image2.Picture.Bitmap.SaveToStream(ms);
  ms.Position:=0;
    begin
      with UIBQuery1 do
      try
        SQL.Clear;
        SQL.Add('INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE');
        SQL.Add('(ID, NAME, PIC)');
        SQL.Add('VALUES');
        SQL.Add('(:ID, :NAME, :PIC)');
        params.AsString[0] := edtID.Text;
        params.AsString[1] := edtName.Text;
        TBLOBField(Params.ByNameAsString['PIC']).LoadFromStream(ms);
        Execute;
        Transaction.Commit;
        bsSkinMessage1.MessageDlg2('Has been saved.','New Record',mtInformation,[mbok],0);
      except
        Transaction.RollBack;
        raise;
      end;
      try
        UIBDataSet1.Close;
        UIBDataSet1.Open;
       except
        raise;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

How's exactly save my TImage to BLOB using UIBQuery? I am really in a heavy stucked.

Comment: Hi. Can you not set it as params.AsString as well? If i remember well, delphi can take binary data in strings.

Comment: Is the above code your actual code?  params.AsInteger[0] seems wrong. To me it should be params[0].AsInteger or similar, but I don't know UIBQuery.  If you can use params[index] you could try params[2].Assign(Image.Picture)

Comment: @Jason; Yes it is In UIB. So, how to implement it? Should be params.AsString[2] := Assign(Image.Picture)? @Martina; no, it's no works.

Comment: @frozenade well, you can't := to Assign as it's a procedure.  Can you params.AsString[2].Assign(Image.Picture)? What is the type returned by AsString[2]? or maybe there's an AsStream[2] you could use and save it via a stream

Comment: @Jason, I tried and unfortunately it fails and there's no AsStream. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
ParamsSetBlob('PIC', ms);
Execute;
...
```

Take a look at UIB source code. Look for TUIBStatement class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following :-

```
Var
  lStream : TMemoryStream;
Begin
  lStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Try
    Image2.Picture.SaveToStream(lStream);
    lStream.Position := 0;
    Query.ParamSetBlob('Pic', lStream);
  Finally
    FreeAndNil(lStream);
  End;
End;
```